# How to style an app migrating to MaterialComponents, AndroidX and AppCompat

Tags: android, androidx, material-components-android

I want to migrate to:

- `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`
- `com.google.android.material:material`

And forget about support library dependencies, but I have some questions:

1. Which style should I use for `ProgressBar` in order to maintain compatibility?

   - v21: `Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal`
   - Support Library: `Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar`
2. When should I use compat styles vs materialcomponents styles?
   Like `@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1` or `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title` ?

Im still confused about `MaterialComponents` and `AppCompat` libraries differences.

Comment: The `MaterialComponents` themes are part of the `com.google.android.material:material` package, while the `AppCompat` themes are part of the (surprise surprise) `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` package.

Comment: The difference is that the `MaterialComponents` implements the new Material Design refresh specs, such as `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`, `com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar`, and so on.

Comment: @Edric but which one should I choose then?

Comment: @Edric if there are no support style then I should use the material one? and viseversa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MaterialComponents is built on top of AppCompat, so generally AppCompat styles will work. However, if a MaterialComponents version of a style exists, you should use that instead.

For ProgressBar specifically, as of now there is no MaterialComponents version so you should use an AppCompat style such as `Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar`. There's more info from a similar question here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/218