# Android Material Components namespace: MaterialComponents vs Design

Tags: material-design, material-components-android

We are migrating over to Material Components + AndroidX

- androidx.appcompat:appcompat
- com.google.android.material:material

Basically same issue as this question: [How to style an app migrating to MaterialComponents, AndroidX and AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53344551/1650674)

I see that the general advice is to pick MaterialComponents over AppCompat. But looking at the material components library, some of the themes/styles are of the format`_____.MaterialComponents.______` and some are `_____.Design.______`.

Here is a [good example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res-public/values/public.xml).

So what is the difference between these two? Why are some styles that are *only* available as `Design` and not `MaterialComponents`? `TextAppearance.Design.Hint` is a good example.